# Why is Intellij Idea freezing during indexing?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, luaj

I'm on Manjaro linux using Intellij Idea community 4:2022.1.3-1 and jdk 17 for this project, maven is also present

Intellij always hangs after it starts indexing the jdk, it's responsive for a period of time but if I type anything or open a new menu after it's begun indexing the jdk it will immediately freeze and I have to kill the process.

This behavior started after I began attempting to use the luaj-jse-3.0.2 library. I got it to successfully start by removing this library once but have been unable to replicate this since.

I have tried -

- Reinstalling intellij
- Installing a different version
- Removing the luaj library (only successful once)
- Deleting the .idea folder
- Running intellij in strace
- Waiting for it to resolve
- Several combinations of all of the above at once

I'm really at my wits' end on this, anyone know anything?

project github (this is up to date to the project): https://github.com/MorticiaGrey/CompSim

Answer (score 0):

Apparently maven was having an issue with the jar I imported through intellij as a library. On a new project without maven but with the offending jar and code copied and pasted from the original project it worked fine, I also got it to work by deleting the old project and importing it again from github without building any of the maven stuff and deleting all the maven files

It may have been my fault for configuring something incorrectly somewhere, but I was using the normal method to add a library in intellij so if that's the case whoops I guess